# How can I get the JSON response from a FormRecognizer document in C#?

Tags: c#, azure-form-recognizer

I'm using FormRecognizer to analyse a document to get the values back like surname: SURNAME.
But with my code I only get the string result without the recognized boxes like above with "surname:" SURNAME.

What I need is the raw json output like you see at the FormRecognizer Builder Website.

Code below:

````
    {
        Debug.Log("using");
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            List<string> list = new List<string>();
            var datei = File.OpenRead(filePath);
            datei.CopyTo(stream);
            stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            AnalyzeDocumentOperation operation = client.StartAnalyzeDocument(modelID, stream);
            operation.WaitForCompletion();
            var result = operation.Value;
            Debug.Log(result);
            string buchstaben = string.Empty;
            foreach(var document in result.Content)
            {
                buchstaben += document;
                
            }
            text.text = buchstaben;

        }
    } ```
````

Comment: Which part of the code is trying to get Json?

Comment: My Question exactly that. My Code can only get the string. I need the json.

Comment: Did you check what `result` and `result.Content` look like? Does the API call supposed to return the Json?

Comment: Can you please add precisely to your question the result that you are getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear if you want to use the SDK to retrieve semantic document fields or raw JSON text, so I'll share a sample for both.

Note that `result.Content` is a string containing the full text of the input document, so your loop is iterating over the `char`'s of the document, not the recognized documents or their fields.

#### Access document fields

This is probably what you want if you are using the SDK to process documents.

```cs
// client is DocumentAnalysisClient
var operation = await client.StartAnalyzeDocumentAsync(modelId, input);
var result = await operation.WaitForCompletionAsync();
Console.WriteLine("Fields:");
foreach (var document in result.Value.Documents)
{
    Console.WriteLine(document.DocType);
    foreach (var (fieldName, fieldValue) in document.Fields)
    {
        // Use fieldValue.AsXyz() to access the strongly-typed value (e.g. AsString(), AsAddress(), etc.).
        Console.WriteLine($"  - {fieldName}: {fieldValue}");
    }
}
```

#### Access raw JSON string

You probably only need this if you are storing results for downstream processing.

```cs
// client is DocumentAnalysisClient
var operation = await client.StartAnalyzeDocumentAsync(modelId, input);
var result = await operation.WaitForCompletionAsync();
var json = result.GetRawResponse().Content.ToString();
Console.WriteLine(json);
```

Comment: Thanks! The first sample might me it but I get 3 errors... 
First two errors are "cannot infer the type of implicitly-typed deconstruction variable "fieldName and fieldValue" 
Last error is: KeyValuePair<string,Documentfield> does not contain a definition for Deconstruct and no accessible extension method Deconstruct" accepting a first argument...are you missing a using directive

Comment: @mrfabian you need to pass in the actual fieldName to replace the code sample shared by Chris. You can find the "Code" tab from Form Recognizer Studio. Or find the repo here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/formrecognizer/Azure.AI.FormRecognizer/samples/Sample_AnalyzeWithPrebuiltModel.md